# Using PHP in Node-Webkit

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, node-webkit

Ive built an AngularJS application over the last several months that utilizes a MySQL database  for its data. This data is fetched by Angular making calls to PHP and PHP returns JSON strings etc.

The issue is once this application is running inside node-webkit, none of the php works, so all of the content areas are empty. I assume (though the documentation on this issue is null and so i have no confirmation) this happens because Node-webkit is a client-side application framework and therefor wont run server-side languages like php. Is there a way to expand node webkit to run php and other server side languages?

I have done my best to find an answer to this question before posting, but documentation for this is nonexistent, and all of the information I have found about node-webkit talks about installing node on your server and installing npms for MySQL and having angular make calls to node. This defeats the purpose of the application entirely as it is designed so that the exe/deb/rpm/dmg can run and you can set up a database with any cloud database provider and be ready to go. Not ideal if you have to buy a vps just to run this one thing.

I have to assume this is possible in some way. i refuse to believe that everyone with an nw application hard codes all their data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you think you need Node-webkit? Note that node.js runs JavaScript on the server while Apache with modphp runs PHP on the server.

Comment: because id like it to be a desktop application not a browser based application. What specifically stops localhost from being the server php executes on in order to call data from a remote DB other than an oversight by the nw developers?

Comment: Its worth Noting that im open to other solutions for this. What im not willing to have is remote scripts on a web server or a Node web server. I need this to run in its wrapper with all calls made from the client's computer (not necessarily client side, just from their computer). This way the shared database can be stored anywhere be it company server, cloud database provider, web host etc.

Comment: this sounds like a website built with angular.js. The client runs the javascrtipt, the server in your case php and mysql. no need for node-webkit or any specific stuff.

Comment: Technical misunderstandings aside, directly connecting a client application to a shared database it a serious security vulnerability, as you application will have to have the database login credentials embedded (which could easily be extracted). An intermediary api (in php or any other language) **is** the way to go

Comment: mb21 i think you misunderstand, i dont want a website. im building a desktop program in node-webkit i do not want to use a local db. I wrote this for building management. Tracking work done to the buildings, contractors used and their info, receipts and invoices (which are scanned using node-printer). The issue is i am one of 3 people who will be using this software at different buildings. Its impractical for us to have separate records. The remedy is having a hosted db that can be referenced. it seems the only way to do this is to call to a php script which seems to be impossible in nw

Comment: Steve even in an SSB with debugging tools disabled?

Comment: @JLGriffin Yes, you can take messures to make it less insecure, but if the credentials are embeded in the app, and you distribute the app to third parties, you are distributing your login credentials.

Comment: Well as of right now it wouldnt be going to third parties art all. it would be for internal usage. furthermore there wouldnt be any logging into the app itself as everything runs from the node-webkit application and theres no other way to access the program as it isnt on a server. only logging in would be to the actual db server and certain settings like that can be stored as a local flatfile. they wouldnt be hard coded into the program itself.

Answer (score 3):

I know of four methods to accomplish this. Some of which you have preferred not to do but I am going to offer them in the hopes it helps you or someone else.

1. Look for an NPM that can do this for you. You should be able to do this functionality within node.js. - https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mysql
2. You can host your PHP remotely. Using `node-remote` you can give this server the appropriate access to your NW.js project.
3. You can code a RESTful PHP application that your JavaScript can pass off information to.
4. You can use my boilerplate code to run PHP within a NW.js project. It however fires up an express.js web server internally to accomplish this. But the server is restricted to the machine and does not accept outside connections - https://github.com/baconface/php-webkit

1 and 4 both carry a risk in your case. Your project can be reversed engineered to reveal the source code and the connection information can be retrieved rather easy. So this should only be in an application on trusted machines and 2 and 3 are the ideal solutions.

Comment: well after a year it seems someone understood what i was trying to do! your php-webkit looks like an ideal solution. i had basically given up on an otherwise great application because there was no way to do what i wanted and i dont want the info publicly available on a website of any kind as per the request of the company i work for. ill let you know how it goes, and ill be sure to ask if i have any issues getting it all setup!

thanks!

Comment: No problem. I have a more up to date version I have been meaning to push to the repo. But this should accomplish what you want to do. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.